# Getting error 'warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast'

Tags: c, linux, strtok

when trying to split a string and put it in an array. I keep getting an error that is in the title. I don't know why, both of the variables are of the char* type. Here is my code:

```
#ifndef CWD_MAX_BUF
#define CWD_MAX_BUF 200
#endif

int main(void) {

int i = 0;
char input[150];
char name[256];
char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX];
char username[LOGIN_NAME_MAX];
char path[CWD_MAX_BUF];
char *data[];   

getcwd(path, CWD_MAX_BUF);
gethostname(hostname, HOST_NAME_MAX);
getlogin_r(username, LOGIN_NAME_MAX);


for(;;){

    printf("[%s@%s %s] $ ", username, hostname, path);
    fgets(input, 150, stdin);

        char *token = strtok(input, " ");

        while (token != NULL){
        
        data[i++] = token;  
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");

        printf("data[%i] = %s\n", i+1, data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What line does this error occur on? How many elements do you think can fit in `char *data[];`? Where are your headers? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `char *data[]` is not a valid array declaration, you need to specify the array size unless there's an initializer (then the size comes from the initializer).

Comment: My guess is that the actual code has `char *data;`, not `char *data[];`. In this case `data[i++]` is a `char`, but `token` is `char*`. You can't do that assignment.

Comment: Yuo should use `strtok(NULL, " \n");` so that the newline at the end of the line will be a delimiter, not part of a token.

Comment: Change the declaration of `data` to `char *data[150];`

Comment: Is the **complete**?  If so, you haven't included the proper header files and `strtok()` will be assumed to return `int` and not `char *`.  That will cause problems on 64-bit systems as the 64-bit pointer value returned by `strtok()` will be truncated to 32 bits before being assigned to the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of bugs:

1. `char *data[];` is *not* valid.
2. It isn't extensible. We want: `char **data = NULL;` and to use `realloc`
3. There is *no* check for the return value of `fgets`, so it will loop *infinitely* and *not* stop at EOF.
4. The second/subsequent calls to `fgets` *obliterate* the data from prior ones. We need to preserve the data using `strdup`.
5. There is *no* stripping of the trailing newline. One way to fix this is to change the delimiters to `strtok` from `" "` to `" \n"`.
6. The final `printf` in the loop tries to print the *next* element rather than the current one. This produces garbage and is UB (undefined behavior) with a dynamically growing array.
7. The pwd, hostname, username isn't part of an MRE (minimal reproducible example).

---

Here is a refactored version.

In the code below, I've used preprocessor conditionals to denote old vs new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Anyway, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef CWD_MAX_BUF
#define CWD_MAX_BUF 200
#endif

int
main(void)
{

    int i = 0;
    char input[150];

#if 0
    char name[256];
    char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX];
    char username[LOGIN_NAME_MAX];
    char path[CWD_MAX_BUF];
#endif

#if 0
    char *data[];
#else
    char **data = NULL;
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: not part of an MRE
#if 0
    getcwd(path, CWD_MAX_BUF);
    gethostname(hostname, HOST_NAME_MAX);
    getlogin_r(username, LOGIN_NAME_MAX);
#endif

    for (;;) {
#if 0
        printf("[%s@%s %s] $ ", username, hostname, path);
#endif
// NOTE/BUG: you don't stop on EOF
#if 0
        fgets(input, 150, stdin);
#else
        if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL)
            break;
#endif

        char *token = strtok(input, " \n");

        while (token != NULL) {
// NOTE/BUG: we need to enlarge data dynamically
// NOTE/BUG: we have to use strdup -- otherwise, the subsequent fgets will
// obliterate the data from the prior line
#if 0
            data[i++] = token;
#else
            data = realloc(data,sizeof(*data) * (i + 1));
            data[i] = strdup(token);
#endif
            printf("TOKEN: %s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");

// NOTE/BUG: tries to print one beyond the end of the actual data
#if 0
            printf("data[%i] = %s\n", i + 1, data[i]);
#else
            printf("data[%i] = %s\n", i, data[i]);
            i++;
#endif
        }
    }

    int count = i;
    for (i = 0;  i < count;  ++i)
        printf("final[%i] = %s\n",i,data[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is some test input:

```
the quick brown fox jumps
over the lazy
dog
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
TOKEN: the
data[0] = the
TOKEN: quick
data[1] = quick
TOKEN: brown
data[2] = brown
TOKEN: fox
data[3] = fox
TOKEN: jumps
data[4] = jumps
TOKEN: over
data[5] = over
TOKEN: the
data[6] = the
TOKEN: lazy
data[7] = lazy
TOKEN: dog
data[8] = dog
final[0] = the
final[1] = quick
final[2] = brown
final[3] = fox
final[4] = jumps
final[5] = over
final[6] = the
final[7] = lazy
final[8] = dog
```